# Why saying that a thread is a "light-weight process" is not technically correct?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, operating-system, distributed-programming

During my distributed programming course in Java, my teacher asked this question. He argued that even if it is a commonly used definition it is not totally true.
What are the things that can make a thread to be considered as a heavy-weight process?

Comment: You ask your teacher for proper references....

Answer (score 0):

There is a definite difference between threads and processes - two or more threads share memory space allocated to the process, while the memory space allocated to 2 processes are separate.

> What are the things that can make a thread to be considered as a
>   heavy-weight process?

Again, the threads are not the same as processes, so this question still technically is still incorrect.

Comment: Note: processes can have  "shared memory" but this is not the default.

Answer (score -3):

heavily/light weight is about how much resources they take and how expensive it is to switch tasks.  On Linux a Thread is also treated like a Process with it's own Process Id, however it doesn't use as much resources as you add each one as it shared memory with an existing thread.

A more light weight version of a thread is to use continuations.  This can be cheapest with short call stacks as it is an entirely user space implementation.

Threads are more light weight than processes. But...

- there are even more light weight was of sharing work, in some contexts threads are expensive.
- it's not really a process (Linux pretends a thread is a process in some ways)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you could argue further that would be great.

Comment: @1z10 what would you like to know. It's a pretty complex subject.

Comment: Just if it is something related with the number of threads being created that makes them to be considered heavy-weigh or if it is related to the need of using synchronized blocks or maybe something deeper at the kernel level and the overheads/disadvantages... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @1z10 see my updated answer.  The number of threads/processes you can have on Linux is the same. You need to use synchronized only if you have multiple threads, you can't use it across multiple processes.